# add onClick listener ChromeOS webview

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I would like to get the event when the user click on anywhere on the webview.
I tried to add a listener like :

```
function EnablelistenerClick() {
    webview.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        // DO SOMETHING
    });
}
```

But I catch none of the event. Is it possible  to catch event like onClick when the user click on a tag div with onClick="javascript:...." ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way by using 
`webview.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e) {
        console.log("loadstart");
    });`